# Why the average of a set of value has the least square error?

Tags: statistics, least-squares

Now we have the equation
$$\sum_{i}(x_i-\hat x_i)^2,$$
where $x_i$ is the observed value of a data sample $S$. Here is the question:

> Why does this expression get its minimum value when $\hat x_i$ is the average of the data sample $S$ ?

I tried to take the derivatives of that equation and make it to zero, but it seems there's something wrong, because $\hat x_i$ is kind of multi-variable. 
Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your notation is confusing.  You can set each $\hat{x}_{i}$ equal to $x_{i}$ to make the sum zero.  Do you want to minimizie $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_{i}-\hat{x})^{2}$, where $\hat{x}$ is a single variable?

Comment: Your expression is confusing.  If $\hat{x_i}$ is an average, why the subscript?

Comment: you are right ! thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Let's take the function:

$$f(\hat x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\hat x)^2$$

Here, we want to find the value of $\hat x$ which minimizes $f(\hat x)$. Now, even though there are multiple variables of this function because of $x_i$, we can just treat these variables as constants since they are independent from the $\hat x$, which essentially changes this to a single-variable calculus problem. Now, let's take the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\hat x$.

$$f'(\hat x)=\sum_{i=1}^n 2(\hat x-x_i)$$

From here, can you find the value of $\hat x$ satisfying $f(\hat x)=0$? Once you solve that equation, use second-derivative test to show that it is indeed an absolute minimum.

Comment: thanks , turns out my notation confuses me..

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved
without calculus.

Let
$f(z)
=\sum_{i}(x_i-z)^2
$.

Then,
since
$\sum_{i}x_i
=n\hat x$,

$\begin{array}\\
f(z)-f(\hat x)
&=\sum_{i}(x_i-z)^2-\sum_{i}(x_i-\hat x)^2\\
&=\sum_{i}((x_i-z)^2-(x_i-\hat x)^2)\\
&=\sum_{i}(x_i^2-2x_iz+z^2-(x_i^2-2x_i\hat x+\hat x^2))\\
&=\sum_{i}(2x_i(\hat x-z)+z^2-\hat x^2)\\
&=2n\hat x(\hat x-z)+n(z^2-\hat x^2)\\
&=2n\hat x(\hat x-z)+n(z-\hat x)(z+\hat x)\\
&=n(\hat x-z)(2\hat x-(z+\hat x))\\
&=n(\hat x-z)(\hat x-z)\\
&=n(\hat x-z)^2\\
&\ge 0
\quad \text{with equality iff } z=\hat x\\
\end{array}
$